# How do I format Outlook restrict to search for a variable?

Tags: python, outlook

I am trying to use the restrict method to search for emails where the subject equals a certain string, however, this string changes slightly everyday since the sender adds the current date. I am trying to use a variable which would contain the current date and insert it into the restrict method.

I keep getting an invalid syntax error message specifically with regards to the Restrict line.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
received_dt = datetime.now()
received_dt = received_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

subject_search_string = "Daily Statement" + recevied_dt

msg = msg.Restrict("[Subject] = " subject_search_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

The subject value must be single-quoted:

```
msg = msg.Restrict("[Subject] = '" subject_search_string "'")
```